# Jenkins doesn't work with repo git organized in folders

Tags: jenkins, github

I'm doing a project for an exam and I'm having trouble connecting jenkins with my own repository (which is organized in folders). In practice, in my repository I have a folder containing some code and another one with some .tex files. When I run the build, jenkins finds the repository but going to see in the workspace it does not generate the build directory containing the .class files. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What commands are you running in your job?

Comment: No command. Sorry, I forgot to add as information that I have a build.gradle file that specifies what needs to be done. Trying with another repo, not organized in folders, does not give me problems and generates the build folder containing the .class.

Comment: You might need to review your gradle file that should not be a problem with jenkins I believe

Comment: I will try to check. The strange thing is that the only thing that has changed is that I simply moved the folders of my java project to a sub-folder. Thanks so much.